# Why is my Express res not being returned to Vue.js component?

Tags: express, vue.js, axios, passport.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to make an axios HTTP request call to an express route to retrieve a response from passport spotify. I am struggling on sending the response from express to my vue.js component. I am using Nuxt.js.

**spotify.vue**

```js
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      userInfo: null
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$axios.get("/auth/spotify")
    .then((response) => {
      userInfo = response;
    }); 
  }
};
```

**server/index.js**

```node
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
const SpotifyStrategy = require('passport-spotify').Strategy;
const keys = require('../config/keys');
const app = express();

async function start () {

  passport.use(
    new SpotifyStrategy(
      {
        clientID: keys.spotifyClientID,
        clientSecret: keys.spotifyClientSecret,
        callbackURL: '/auth/spotify/callback'
      },
      function(accessToken, refreshToken, expires_in, profile, done) {
        console.log(profile);
      }
    )
  );

  app.get('/auth/spotify', passport.authenticate('spotify'), function(req,res) {
    res.json(data);
  });

  app.get('/auth/spotify/callback', passport.authenticate('spotify'));

}
```

When accessing *localhost:3000/auth/spotify* the data I am looking for is logged. I am wondering why *res.json()* or *res.send()* is not passing the data to the axios promise in my component.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Do you see any error messages in the browser console? Can you see the relevant request in the Network tab of the developer tools? Does the request succeed? I assume 3000 is your Express server and Vue is served from some other port? How are you linking the two servers: are you proxying requests to Express or using CORS? Do you have a `baseURL` set for axios?

Comment: I don't know if it's important, but here you probably have a bug `userInfo = response` instead `this.userInfo = response`?